My cactus is brown
I have a potted cactus and it’s brown at the bottom but still green on the inside it’s a bit soft but not as hard as I would like it to be. I hadn’t watered it in a while (a few months). I watered it and put it in an area that gets more air and light. Should I just propagate it or can it still be saved. The roots seem to be fine too.

Pictures please!

You haven't watered in months? Now is a good time.
